# Table format output from SSIS to C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, output, tabular

I'm able to call SSIS Package and get the result of package execution status from C# application. The problem is I want to retrieve the a tabular data which is output from SSIS package to C# application.

I aware of the options of staging the resultant data to a SQL Server table / to a CSV file and then let C# application read the data. I'm looking for directly reading the data output from SSIS to C#. I'm not sure if this is possible. Please could you share your thoughts on how to achieve this.

Limitations : I can't read the data of the database from C#. It has to be routed through SSIS after a series of transformations.

Comment: Maybe using SSIS to call a webservice that can communicate to your application?

Comment: @TabAlleman : Yes, seems that possible. However this adds more application layers in the project. Just wondering if a simple solution could be available.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible, SSIS won't output that data for you. As you've suggested, you'll need SSIS to write the data to a destination (SQL Server, flat file, etc.) that your application can then read in as another step.